# Git checkout tag leads to “Not currently on any branch”

Tags: git, version-control, git-tag

I encountered really strange issue for me with tag checkout. After merging latest changes from develop into master I created a tag from master and pushed to remote. Then on production pulled successfully but when I checkout the tag and run git status I get

> Not currently on any branch

On my local machine git status properly show that head is detached at the specific tag, for example 1.0.0

```
git branch -v
* (no branch) ca992e2 Example commit message
develop     e945a50 Example commit message
master      ca992e2 Example commit message
```

Any tips?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a "normal" behaviour.
By checking out on a tag, you position the HEAD of your local repository to the tag. You are no longer on a branch. This does not matter if you do not intend to make any change

If you need to make a change, I would see two options :

1. you want to continue working on the branch where you were located when you applied the tag. You should then checking out to that branch.
2. you need to perform a fix based on the tag you create and that fix cannot be on the branch you initially used to create the tag. You would then need to create a new branch starting from that tag.
   The command would then be :

   > git checkout -b new-branch tag

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, it makes sense but Im still trying to figure out why on one machine git status show `Not currently on any branch` while the same setup on another machine shows `HEAD detached at v1.0.0` What is causing this difference in git status? Except this everything else is fine, proper commit is checked out and there are no differences in the files.

Comment: @tslid : what does `git version` say on production and on your local machine ?

Comment: Okay thats it - 1.7 vs 2.13 This was whats bothering me, there is no actual issue but I couldnt find this in git documentation. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is correct (and I've upvoted it).  To detail the last bit—that one Git, a positively ancient 1.7, just says that you have a detached HEAD, but a more modern one, 2.13, says that you have a HEAD that is `detached at v1.0.0`—the `git status` command got many very useful and important boosts in functionality over the years between these two releases.

It's not clear exactly when the "detached at / from" code went in as this is not listed in [the release notes](https://github.com/git/git/tree/master/Documentation/RelNotes), but here's a laundry list of useful items:

- 1.7.1: `git status` learned about submodules
- 1.7.2: `git status` can include branch name in `-s -b` output
- 1.7.3.5: `git status` learned to quote unprintable characters in path names
- 1.7.6: `git status -z` fixes (important if you use it in scripts)
- 1.7.10.13: more `git status --porcelain` and `git status -z` fixes (again, for scripts)
- 1.7.11.3: `git status` (and `git diff` itself) fixed to handle files named `-`
- 1.8.2: `git status` learned to say which branch is being bisected or rebased, during these operations
- 1.8.3: `git status` learned to report about being in the middle of a `git revert`, too
- 1.8.4: `git status` learned configuration options `status.branch` and `status.short`
- 1.8.5: `git status` improved several reports: submodules, cherry-picks, and status of the current branch (if any) with respect to its upstream
- 2.4.0: `git status` learned `-v -v`, and its `detached at` / `detached from` is improved and synchronized with that of `git branch`
- 2.5.0: `git status` says more about an ongoing interactive rebase
- 2.6.2: `git status` no longer says the useless `HEAD detached at HEAD`

The "detached at" or "detached from" state is computed by scanning the reflog for `HEAD`, so it's not 100% reliable depending on just what you get stuck into the reflog.  It's still very useful.